# confusion with my variable in perl

Tags: perl

If using `use strict` and `use warning` and
if I specify `my` datatype, it works; if I do not specify the `my` it says error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $test=10;
my @arr=(10,20,30);
```

If I declare the array variable name as a number:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my @100=(10,20,30);
```

then when I run that program it says error:

```
 Can't use global @100 in "my" at number_sclar.pl line 28, near "my @100"
```

If I remove that `my` and run that program, it runs without an error.

So please can anyone tell me why `my` variable is not supported with a numeric array variable name?

Comment: i want to know the working principle of my variable.. that is why i posted here.

Comment: Well, I don't have a good explanation; I'd hazard a guess that it is provided for backwards compatibility, consonant with the special variables such as `$^W`.  FYI: you can use `our @100 = (10, 20, 30);` and `print $100[0];` without triggering an error.  The combination of warnings and `my` means that numeric names are not acceptable.

Comment: hmm.  never thought that would work.

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob: I was more than a little surprised too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an unintentional side-effect of creating $1, $2, $3, $100, etc (to hold the results of regex captures); @1, @2, @3, @100, etc also get created.

However, the name of these and most of the special vars in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) aren't legal names except for package vars. For example, you can't do `my $(;` or `sub (;` even though though `$(` is a valid name for a package variable<sup>[1]</sup>.

When lexicals were added to Perl in 5.6, it was surely deemed to be to confusing to allow such names for user variables. In fact, I doubt anyone even entertained the thought.

Sigil aside, lexical vars must start with a character in [a-zA-Z_]<sup>[2]</sup> and can be followed by a number of characters in [a-zA-Z0-9_]<sup>[2]</sup>. As such, `@100` is not a valid name for a lexical variable.

---

Notes:

1. ```
   >perl -e"our $(;"

   >perl -e"my $(;"
   Can't use global $( in "my" at -e line 1, near "my $("
   Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

   >perl -e"sub (;"
   Prototype not terminated at -e line 1.
   ```
2. More code points are actually allowed, but they fall outside of ASCII's character set. For simplicity, I only listed the code points that fall inside of ASCII's character set.

Comment: I thought that was only $1 - $9

Comment: @jozefg, It isn't, as you could have verified with a test.

Answer (score 9):

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Perl identifiers that begin with digits, control characters, or
>   punctuation characters are exempt from the effects of the "package"
>   declaration
>          and are always forced to be in package "main"; **they are also exempt from "strict 'vars'" errors.**  A few other names are also exempt
>   in these ways...

Comment: How did this get 10 votes? It doesn't even try to answer the OP's question! The fact that package variables exist with those names has nothing to do with the inability to declare them with `my`. e.g. `$a` and `$_` are exempt from strictures, but they can be declared with `my`.